# Can I boot my mac without pressing the power key?

Tags: keyboard, startup, hardware, power

Back in the day you could start a Macintosh using the power key on the keyboard (like the Apple Extended 2 has one in the top right).

These days we have many (more) input options like: Power, USB, Ethernet, HDMI, Thunderbolt, Audio in/out, SD card reader, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth.

I have a MacMini (2011) which is under the desk. Is it possible to boot a mac (or my Mini) after a shutdown WITHOUT pressing the power button?

*I tried the 'Start up automatically after a power failure' but after a cold shutdown, a power cord disconnect/connect did not boot my computer.*

[image: Apple Extended 2]
[image: Energy Saver start up automatically after a power failure]

Comment: *many* years ago I bought a power strip that you could plug all your Mac stuff into and then turn everything on with the keyboard power button. It **rocked!** And then I got my first Mac without an ADB port and was informed that USB did not support such things and that I was, unfortunately, SOL. In the many years since I have never seen such a thing again. I would bet that such a thing still does not exist.

Comment: What percentage of Macs in the last 10 or so years **don't** have a power key on the keyboard? Mac Pros don't, but all laptops do. Not sure about iMacs. I'm wondering what's the practical intent of this question.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I am that guy with a MacMini (2011) ;) I have it put away under the desk. I'll update the question.

Comment: Ah, yup, forgot about minis. Workaround - don't shut it down, let it sleep, then it will wake when you tap the spacebar. I've a building full of Mac Pros here & that's pretty much how they're treated. Additional benefit for me - you can wake them with remote desktop too.

Comment: What do you mean by cold shutdown?

Comment: I'd second the comments to leave it on. I had a 2012 Mini, whose power button was hard to reach, so I left it permanently on for six years (not including restarts for updates and to blow out the cobwebs). My new 2018 has also been permanently on since new. The power consumption when sleeping is very light.

Answer (score 4):

## shutdown -u

> I tried the 'Start up automatically after a power failure' but after a cold shutdown, a power cord disconnect/connect did not boot my computer.

The automatic power on only works if the power was cut. You can induce this behaviour using the command `shutdown -u now`. According to [man shutdown](https://ss64.com/osx/shutdown.html) the `-u` flag does the following:

> `-u`: The system is halted up until the point of removing system power,
> but waits before removing power for 5 minutes so that an external
> UPS (uninterruptible power supply) can forcibly remove power.
> This simulates a dirty shutdown to permit a later automatic power
> on. OS X uses this mode automatically with supported UPSs in
> emergency shutdowns.

Comment: Neat trick. So you need to be root and shutdown -u requires -h. So the command is  `sudo shutdown -u -h now`. This will halt the machine, but does not let it boot. I think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: This approach is not ideal, nor practical for daily use, but helps explain that there are special requirements to the automatic power on after power failure.